# Twilio | Wso2 : ERROR {NativeWorkerPool} - Uncaught exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: wso2, twilio, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm using **Twilio connector** for Wso2 and I'm facing an issue (as shown below) while deploying the .car file on micro Integrator runtime, however when I run the connector on embedded server that comes with integration studio things work pretty fine. Any solution to that?

```
[2022-10-07 15:31:24,320] ERROR {NativeWorkerPool} - Uncaught exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at com.twilio.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:35)
        at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:54)
        at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:45)
        at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:36)
        at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.build(TwilioRestClient.java:143)
        at com.twilio.Twilio.buildRestClient(Twilio.java:202)
        at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient(Twilio.java:174)
        at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.connector.twilio.sms.SendSms.connect(SendSms.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.AbstractConnector.mediate(AbstractConnector.java:32)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:94)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:134)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:331)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:448)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:120)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:98)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:99)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:426)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have checked and it seems that the error is due to the incompatible **org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient** runtime version.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
     <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
     <version>4.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm not sure where to add this dependency in **Wso2**.

Comment: What's the MI version you are using?

Comment: I have used windows Installer for EI 7.0.1 and it has installed MI 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to add external Jars to the runtime, in this case, this could conflict with existing dependencies. Having said that, as per the [Connector Store](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/f33557eb-65c5-4119-b0cb-3b89f287dc04) latest Twillio connector is not compatible with MI 1.2.0. Hence best option is to try upgrading to a newer version of MI(4.X). Should work in any 4.0+ versions.

Else you can try using the older version of the connector. (version 1.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the GA pack? Can you try updating the MI to the latest u2 level and check. We have done a Httpclient component upgrade in all the latest MI versions